# R 3.2 on AWS AMI

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am trying to install R with Rstudio on an Amazon AWS AMI. It currently ships R-3.1 and I would like it to have R-3.2. I am currently using 2013.03 release but the new [2015](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2015.03-packages/) version also doesn't have the right version.

The `yum install R` command won't upgrade it.

```
root@ip-172-31-3-136 tmp]$ sudo yum install R
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                          
                                      | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                       
                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
704 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package R-3.1.1-3.18.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I figured I'd add another rpm repo, so I download the rpm list from the most recent CentOS.

```
wget http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
sudo yum localinstall epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install R
```

This also doesn't work and gives me a list of errors like:

```
Error: Package: python26-2.6.9-1.80.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-17.10.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
           Updated By: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
Error: libdb4 conflicts with filesystem-2.4.30-3.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Package: rpm-python26-4.11.2-2.64.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-17.10.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
           Updated By: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: httpd-2.2.29-1.5.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-17.10.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
           Updated By: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
```

I am trying to install R as part of a provisioning script so preferably I would be able to to not have to install from source as this takes a LONG time.

The `--enablerepo=epel` trick also does not work either.

```
root@ip-172-31-3-136 tmp]$ sudo yum install R --enablerepo=epel
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                    | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                 | 2.3 kB     00:00
704 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package R-3.1.1-3.18.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

This all seems very confusing as the following script does work on a CENTOS 7 box when I start it on digital ocean:

```
[root@servy-server ~]# yum install -y epel-release
[root@servy-server ~]# yum update -y
[root@servy-server ~]# yum install -y R
[root@servy-server ~]# R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Amazon AWS AMI now ships with R version 3.2.

Comment: Cool. This is new to me and will help avoid this problem in the future.